# Efficiency of findViewById

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, findviewbyid

Probably most Android devs know that `findViewById` is not a cheap operation. Another thing that most of us know, is that you can boost the performance by using the smallest sub-tree of the view hierarchy to find views by their id, example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/some_id_0">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/some_id_1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/some_id_2">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/textview" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In this case you probably want to search in the `LinearLayout` with the `id == @id/textview`

But what is the case when the hierarchy is not cascading, but rather branching on every level, and you want to find the views on the "leaves" let's say? Do you perform the `findViewById` to get to the bottom of the branch by finding parents, OR do you perform the `findViewById` on a larger subset? I think a simple answer would be that it depends on the case, but maybe we could generalize a bit on what it really depends?

Thanks

## **EDIT:**

By a larger subset I mean something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/r0">    
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/r1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/some_id_0">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/some_id_1">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/some_id_2">
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/textview0" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/some_id_3">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/some_id_4">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/some_id_5">
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/textview1" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/some_id_6">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/some_id_7">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/some_id_8">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/textview2" />
                <TextView android:id="@+id/textview3" />
                <TextView android:id="@+id/textview4" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So the question would be if I want to `findViewById` the `TextView` views in `LinearLayout` with `@+id/some_id_8`, should I perform this operation on the whole container, or I should `findViewById` the `LinearLayout` with `@+id/some_id_8` and on this view `findViewById` all the `TextViews`?

Comment: Can you explain more your 2 alternatives, especially the "findViewById on a larger subset" ?

Comment: The [default traversal](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java#3246) is depth first. Finding a subtree first smells like micro-optimization that makes the code slightly harder to maintain. Measure to find out if it really makes a difference

Comment: As laalto already mentioned findViewById() will iterate over the entire view hierarchy so using the two findViewById() calls will not make any difference(other than you'll have one extra line of code). If you have an intimate knowledge about the view hierarchy you could use a combination of getChild() and findViewById() which should be faster in some casses(not that it will matter) but will make the code very rigid to any future changes. In the end the depth and size of the view hierarchy will be more important for performance then searching for those views.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It makes absolutely no difference if you look for the `View` directly or if you look for a parent first and then the child. But if you for example want to retrieve the three `TextViews` in the `LinearLayout` with the id `some_id_8` then it would be better for performance if you first look for the `LinearLayout` and then for the `TextViews`. But the difference is miniscule. The real problem is **the layout itself** (more on that further down).

And generally `findViewById()` is not the source of all evil. It can be a problem in a `ListView` if you have to call `findViewById()` possibly even several times during each `getView()` call, but that's what the view holder pattern is for.

When performance is critical see to it that you call `findViewById()` as little as possible. In  a `Fragment` or `Activity` you can look for all the `Views` you will ever need in `onCreateView()` or `onCreate()`. If you save the references in a few member variables you will never have to call it again.

---

Now to explain why `findViewById()` can be a performance problem we have to look at its implementation, [**this link leads to the Android 4.4.4 View source code**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/view/View.java#View.findViewById%28int%29):

```
public final View findViewById(int id) {
    if (id < 0) {
        return null;
    }
    return findViewTraversal(id);
}
```

So `findViewById()` just checks if the id is valid, and if it is then the protected method `findViewTraversal()` is called. In a `View` it is implemented like this:

```
protected View findViewTraversal(int id) {
    if (id == mID) {
        return this;
    }
    return null;
}
```

It just checks if the passed in id is equal to the id of the `View` and returns `this` if it does, otherwise `null`. The interesting part is the `findViewTraversal()` implementation of `ViewGroup`, [**this links leads to the Android 4.4.4 ViewGroup source code**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/view/ViewGroup.java#ViewGroup.findViewTraversal%28int%29):

```
protected View findViewTraversal(int id) {
    if (id == mID) {
        return this;
    }

    final View[] where = mChildren;
    final int len = mChildrenCount;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        View v = where[i];

        if ((v.mPrivateFlags & PFLAG_IS_ROOT_NAMESPACE) == 0) {
            v = v.findViewById(id);

            if (v != null) {
                return v;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

The first if at the top of this method is the same as in the `View` implementation, it just checks if the passed in id equals the id of the `ViewGroup` and if it does it returns itself. After that it loops through all the children and calls `findViewById()` on each of the children, if the return value of this call is not `null` then the `View` we are looking for has been found and will be returned.

<sub>If you want more details about how `Views` or `ViewGroups` work I suggest you study the source code yourself!</sub>

---

So this all seems pretty straight forward. The view hierarchy is essentially traversed like a tree. And that can make it pretty expensive or pretty fast depending on how many `Views` are in your layout. It doesn't matter if your layout looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/some_id_0">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/some_id_1">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/some_id_2">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/textview0" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Or if it looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/some_id_0">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/some_id_1" />
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/some_id_2" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textview0" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Because the amount of `Views` is the same in both cases, and the performance of `findViewById()` scales with the amount of the `Views`.

**BUT** the general rule is that you should try to reduce the complexity of the layout to increase performance and that you should often use a `RelativeLayout`. And that works just because if you reduce the complexity you also reduce the amount of `Views` in the layout and `RelativeLayouts` are very good at reducing complexity. Let me illustrate that, image you have a layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/some_id_0">
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/some_id_5">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/some_id_1" />
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/some_id_2" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/some_id_6">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/some_id_3" />
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/some_id_4" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Imagine that in this case both of the `RelativeLayouts` above are just there to position the inner `LinearLayouts` in some special way and the outer `LinearLayout` is just there to position the `RelativeLayouts` below each other. You can very easily build the same layout with just a `RelativeLayout` as a root and the four `LinearLayouts` as children:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/some_id_0">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/some_id_1" />
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/some_id_2" />
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/some_id_3" />
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/some_id_4" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the performance of that layout will be better than the layout above not because the `RelativeLayout` is somehow performance-wise better than a `LinearLayout` and not because the layout is flatter, but simply because the amount of `Views` in the layout is lower. The same applies for almost all other view-related processes like drawing, layouting, measuring. Everything will be faster just because the amount of `Views` in the layout is lower.

---

And to return to your original question: If you want a performance increase than reduce the complexity of your layout. There is absolutely no reason to have so many nested `LinearLayouts`. Your "large subset" can almost certainly be reduced to this:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/r0">  
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textview0" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textview1" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textview2" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textview3" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textview4" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And such a layout would definitely yield a big performance boost.

Comment: Problem with "Probably most Android devs know that findViewById is not a cheap operation" is that few seem to even think what it does actually. Even googles own mouthpieces don't seem to stop to consider it at all.

for example the much touted "viewholder" pattern for a listview doesn't improve things much at all if you have single digit amounts of views in the layout as is usual for listview items and you use the convertview. a single drawable or text change is going to be slower than the view searches. I'd like someone to benchmark that actually..

Comment: `RelativeLayout is somehow performance-wise better than a LinearLayout` this seems 90% wrong to me.

Comment: @mvai Not a `LinearLayout`, many `LinearLayouts` or any complex layout. Sure one `RelativeLayout` will be performance wise worse than a `LinearLayout` for many reason for example the need for two layout passes in `RelativeLayouts` etc. However if you use the `RelativeLayout` for the purpose it was made for - to create complex relative layouts without having to nest many layouts then the `RelativeLayout` really shines. Of course today everything is different. The `CoordinatorLayout` with its `Behaviors` is extremly flexible and very complicated layouts can be implemented with it in a snap.

Comment: @mvai So nowadays most layouts are built based on a `CoordinatorLayout`, but still the `RelativeLayout` is good for exactly the purpose it was made for: To simplify layouts. I mean just look at the many nested layouts in the question. Do you really think that all those `LinearLayouts` are performance wise better than just using one `RelativeLayout`? And that's exactly what my answer is about.

Comment: Ok, sounds better now :-) sorry if my comment seemed rude. I don't know at which point a RelativeLayout starts performing better than nested LinearLayouts, but yes, it surely does at some point. Just wanted to point out that it's never better than a *single* LinearLayout (due to the two layout passes).

Comment: A bit OT, but recently I've been transforming some layouts in my app - mostly RelativeLayouts with complex child dependencies - to FrameLayouts, arranging childs simply with `layout_margin` and  `layout_gravity`. It's not neat and you can't always do that, but you get the same flatness and I have seen great improvements in performance, mostly in adapter views.

Comment: @mvai Yes, `FrameLayout`s are great if you use them the right way. `layout_gravity` gives you a lot of freedom in the placement of `Views` and the whole measuring and layouting process of a `FrameLayout` is fast. But then again that's what makes the `CoordinatorLayout` so great, it is a `FrameLayout` with extra functionality.

Comment: One point worths mentioning I think. The main reason we want to keep it flat is because of the recursive methods - requestLayout() and invalidate(). Once you call one of those, they go all the way up to the root of the view hierarchy and schedule (ignoring platform optimizations) top-down measure + layout passes for each call. And the more deep your hierarchy, the more you schedule traversals.

Comment: why they don't use a dictionary to hold id`s with their corresponding view? seems like a great performance improvement. unless there is a reason they cant do that?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at that android source code I just don't see how findViewById is expensive at all. It's basically a simple loop, I know it's recursive so you'll pay the penalty of constantly switching the stack, but even the most complicated screen is going to be in the order of dozens of Views not thousands, except for recycled lists. I guess we need benchmarks on low end devices to know if it's really an issue.

Comment: I think so. It's expensive until you findViewById in a loop such as listview.