# [Android preformance]:Shoud i findViewById every time i need it or make it a field variable

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

What is better for the memory managment and preformance? 
call the element when is needed or if it will be needed multiple times make it a field variable 
For example:

```
 private void setNumber(int intNumber) {
        TextView number = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.number);

        String numberString = "#" + String.valueOf(intNumber);
        number.setText(numberString);
        number.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(1000).start();
        number = null;

    }
```

in this function every time the function is called the element `number` is called by its id but maybe do this its too much expensive and don't conpensates the fact that while its not needed that memory will not be free and do this is better.

```
class{
    TextView number;

    constructor{

    number = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.number);

    }

private void setNumber(int intNumber) {

    String numberString = "#" + String.valueOf(intNumber);
    number.setText(numberString);
    number.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(1000).start();
    number = null;

    }
}
```

slide note: this element will be needed approximately every 60s

Comment: use 2nd option ,it's better

Comment: You could not use it, and just use a View Injection library like ButterKnife handle it for you

Comment: Variable.  FindViewById is an O(n) walk through the view.  That's why view holders are used in listview adapters- to avoid an O(n) walk every time you bind the view.  I'd vote against anything like butterknife, any time you have magic annotations doing things for you your code becomes less readable and maintainable.

Comment: ButterKnife is just an extra lib burden , just a  fancy thing, it does almost the same thing as `findviewbyid`  , totally agree with @GabeSechan

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to check this post [Efficiency of findViewById](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037744/efficiency-of-findviewbyid)

Because calling **findviewbyid** can cost alot of performance, is you have plenty of views you want to manipulate.